# BUSCADOR INTERNO

Tags: javascript, buscador

Estoy haciendo un buscador para mi pagina web con javascrip. Mi problema es que el buscador no funciona del todo bien. La funcionalidad que quiero que tenga es que, por ejemplo, cuando aplaste la letra "a" me aparezcan todas las opciones que tengan esta letra pero no pasa eso sino que cuando ingreso "a" en el input, solo sale una palabra completa pero las otras opciones ya no. Gracias de ante mano.
Este es mi codigo JS.

```
let newArrayAthletes = Array.from(arrayAthletes);
let search = document.querySelector('.search');
let lista = document.querySelector('.lista');
let searching = () =>{ 
  lista.innerHTML ="";
  let texto = search.value.toLowerCase();
  for (const athletes of newArrayAthletes) {
    let name= athletes.name.toLowerCase();
  //console.log(name);
    if (name.indexOf(texto) > -1) {    
       lista.innerHTML= `<li>${athletes.name}-</li>`
    }
  }
}
search.addEventListener('keyup', searching);
```

Este es mi codigo HTML

```
<input type="text" id="search" class="search" 
placeholder="¿Qué deseas buscar?">
      <div class="boxSearch" id="boxSearch">
        <ul id="lista" class="lista">  </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: Si el nombre contiene lo que has digitado, metes ese valor en el `innerHTML` de lista.... si el nombre del siguiente atleta del array contiene lo que has digitado, ***machacas*** el `innerHTML` con ese nombre y el anterior se pierde. Pero esto no es un funcionamiento anormal, es exactamente lo que has indicado tú en esta línea: `lista.innerHTML= <li>${athletes.name}-</li>`. Si quieres que eso no suceda, te recomiendo que concatenes en vez de asignar. Por ejemplo `lista.innerHTML += ...`. Teoría básica de operadores, `=` asigna, `+=` concatena.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Lo probé y ya me salió.